# android detect when car moving and stopping

Tags: android, performance, gps

I am building an app that detects when the car is moving or parking by detecting its speed.
I have some code that detects the current speed, but I don't know how to write that code so if the speed is over 20 km/h so do anything, and if the speed is 0 km/h so do anything.

Here is my code:

```
public class DeviceSpeedDemoActivity extends Activity implements GPSCallback{
    private GPSManager gpsManager = null;
    private double speed = 0.0;
    private int measurement_index = Constants.INDEX_KM;
    private AbsoluteSizeSpan sizeSpanLarge = null;
    private AbsoluteSizeSpan sizeSpanSmall = null;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        gpsManager = new GPSManager();

        gpsManager.startListening(getApplicationContext());
        gpsManager.setGPSCallback(this);

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_message)).setText(getString(R.string.info));

        measurement_index = AppSettings.getMeasureUnit(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGPSUpdate(Location location) 
    {
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();
            speed = location.getSpeed();

            String speedString = "" + roundDecimal(convertSpeed(speed),2);
            String unitString = measurementUnitString(measurement_index);

            setSpeedText(R.id.info_message,speedString + " " + unitString);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
            gpsManager.stopListening();
            gpsManager.setGPSCallback(null);

            gpsManager = null;

            super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

            return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            boolean result = true;

            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
                    case R.id.menu_about:
                    {
                            displayAboutDialog();

                            break;
                    }
                    case R.id.unit_km:
                    {
                            measurement_index = 0;

                            AppSettings.setMeasureUnit(this, 0);

                            break;
                    }
                    case R.id.unit_miles:
                    {
                            measurement_index = 1;

                            AppSettings.setMeasureUnit(this, 1);

                            break;
                    }
                    default:
                    {
                            result = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

                            break;
                    }
            }

            return result;
    }
     private double convertSpeed(double speed){
            return ((speed * Constants.HOUR_MULTIPLIER) * Constants.UNIT_MULTIPLIERS[measurement_index]); 
    }

    private String measurementUnitString(int unitIndex){
            String string = "";

            switch(unitIndex)
            {
                    case Constants.INDEX_KM:                string = "km/h";        break;
                    case Constants.INDEX_MILES:     string = "mi/h";        break;
            }

            return string;
    }

    private double roundDecimal(double value, final int decimalPlace)
    {
            BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);

            bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlace, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            value = bd.doubleValue();

            return value;
    }

    private void setSpeedText(int textid,String text)
    {
            Spannable span = new SpannableString(text);
            int firstPos = text.indexOf(32);

            span.setSpan(sizeSpanLarge, 0, firstPos,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            span.setSpan(sizeSpanSmall, firstPos + 1, text.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            TextView tv = ((TextView)findViewById(textid));

            tv.setText(span);
    }

    private void displayAboutDialog()
    {
            final LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View settingsview = inflator.inflate(R.layout.about, null);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            builder.setView(settingsview);

            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
            });

            builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why if-then-else is not suitable?

Comment: put some condition if-else something like that.

Comment: You should look into the new location recognition. It basically do all these heavy lifting for you. http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

Answer (score 0):

In your method `onGPSUpdate()`, you should be able to determine this criteria.

```
@Override
public void onGPSUpdate(Location location) 
{
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();
    speed = location.getSpeed();

    double speedKPH = convertSpeed(speed);

    if(speedKPH > 20.0)
    {
        //Do something, Speed Over 20
    }else if(speedKPH == 0)
    {
        //Do something else, speed 0
    }

    String speedString = "" + roundDecimal(convertSpeed(speed),2);
    String unitString = measurementUnitString(measurement_index);

    setSpeedText(R.id.info_message,speedString + " " + unitString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `if-elseif` block. When you are getting your speed, i.e. `onGPSUpdate`, just add the following:

```
if(convertSpeed(speed) > 20.0){
    //Code for Speed Over 20
}
else{
    //code for speed less than 20
}
```

By the way when using `location.getLongitude()` use a `try-catch` block, as they don't work well always, and you don't want to annoy the user with a force-close.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem for a flight logging application. I wanted to detect the begin of taxiing to the runway, the take-off, landing, and reaching the parking position, plus some more complex things as touch-and-goes.

A useful pattern here is a state machine (or the state pattern): Your app maintains a state (e.g. stopped, or running; in my example parking, taxi-for-take-off, in-flight, and so on). If in a certain state you look for different events: E.g. if in state "stopped" you look if the speed exceeds a certain threshold, e.g. 5 km/h or if the location changes and certain distance threshold is exceeded. If in state "driving" you check for the speed dropping below a certain threshold and if that happens you look if it stays below that thereshold for some time (if you want to avoid detecting a short stop like taking a turn). And so on.
Thus your app is in a certain state which determines the interpretation of sensor events. Your apps evaluates the sensor events wrt. to the current state and switches state if the evaluations supports a hypothesis that the state should be changed.